# Add additional properties to .aar / pom file

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

i have the following scenario:

I have an android library project in gradle, containing 2 submodules:

MyLibProject
   - SubModule1
   - SubModule2

In MyLibProjects build.gradle file I have defined variables like this:

```
ext {
  daggerVersion = "1.2.2"
}
```

SubModule1 and SubModule2 has a dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:'+rootProject.ext.daggerVersion
}
```

So far so good. I can build .aar library out of them and deploy them to my maven repository, everything is fine.

Now I want to include MyLibProject in an android application project. So I include my library project which already include dagger. However, dagger's annotation processing compiler needs to be included in the application project by using hugo vissers android-apt gradle plugin

```
dependecies {
  compile 'com.company:mylibproject:1.0.0'
  apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
}
```

So far so good, everything is working quite well.
I only have one "problem" that I want to solve. The problem I'm talking about is that in my application I have to know the version of dagger-compiler. Is there a way to put the extra information like MyLibProject's ext into the maven / aar files so that I can access them somehow in the applications build.gradle file?

Is something like this (applications build.gradle file) possible:

```
dependecies {
  compile 'com.company:mylibproject:1.0.0'
  apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:'+MyLibraryProject.ext.daggerVersion
}
```

I mean, is it possible to get the version of dagger out of the library projects file or is there a gradle plugin to get the version of dagger?

Comment: I'm assuming some plugin needs the dagger-compiler dependency to be included the `apt` configuration? Could you then just have the `apt` configuration extend from `compile` since you know the `compile` configuration will contain the correct version of the dependency you need?

Comment: Instead of `rootProject.ext.daggerVersion`, `daggerVersion` should be used. `.ext` should only be used when defining an extra variable.

Comment: Just to clarify, it looks like you application project is bringing in your library as an external module dependency, correct? If so, you won't be able to access the library project's properties. Not unless they are both part of a single multi-project build.

Comment: @MarkVieira correct! and that's the problem, they are two complete separated projects, therefore Peter Niederwieser your suggestion does not work. The library project is included as .aar and pom.xml. I thought there might be a way to add extra properties in the libraries pom.xml file which can be read somehow.

Comment: @MarkVieira your suggestion seems the most promising one. However there are two issues: annotation processing doesn't starts with scope provided in libraries pom.xml for dagger-compile and if I simply use compile (instead of provide) then it will include dagger-compiler's dependencies like guava as well in my app what I want avoid.

Comment: @sockeqwe My comment was on an issue with the build script, namely that `.ext` should only be used when defining an extra variable. Of course this won't solve your problem. As to your problem, I don't see an easy solution, and I'd probably just live with the duplication.